# Widget right click pops up wrong place

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I added right click action to widget embedded in `QTableWidget`. When I click right `QMenu` appears in wrong place. Here is my code:

I added widget in `QTableWidget`:

```
        tableWidget = self._dlg.tableWidget
        variableLabel = QLabel()
        variableLabel.setText(str(var))
        variableLabel.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        variableLabel.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showMenu)
        tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 0, variableLabel)
```

And here showMenu:

```
def showMenu(self, pos):
    print("pos", str(pos))
    menu = QMenu()
    applyAction = menu.addAction("Tümüne Uygula")
    action = menu.exec_(self._dlg.mapToGlobal(pos))
    if action == applyAction:
    ...
```

Lastly, here is my result, when I click colored cell (`QLabel`) the menu appears below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the position sent by `customContextMenuRequested` is relative to the widget that issued it, in your case to the `QLabel`, assuming that `showMenu()` belongs to any widget we can use the `sender()` method to obtain it.

```
def showMenu(self, pos):
    menu = QMenu()
    applyAction = menu.addAction("Tümüne Uygula")
    action = menu.exec_(self.sender().mapToGlobal(pos))
    if action == applyAction:
```

If `showMenu()` does not belong to a widget then it will have to pass the label explicitly using `functools.partial`

```
from functools import partial

...

        tableWidget = self._dlg.tableWidget
        variableLabel = QLabel()
        variableLabel.setText(str(var))
        variableLabel.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        variableLabel.customContextMenuRequested.connect(partial(self.showMenu, variableLabel))
        tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 0, variableLabel)

    ...

def showMenu(self, label, pos):
    menu = QMenu()
    applyAction = menu.addAction("Tümüne Uygula")
    action = menu.exec_(label.mapToGlobal(pos))
    if action == applyAction:
    ...
```

Comment: sender() works perfectly! But I don't understand functools.partial it does not work?